# Can I have the PC version display a PS3 controller layout?

Tags: kingdoms-of-amalur-reckoning, motioninjoy-ds3tool

The only reason I even considered picking up Kingdoms of Amalur for the PC was the fact that the game still supports a gamepad.

Since I own a PS3, my gamepad of choice is one of my PS3 controllers hooked up to the PC, while using MotionInJoy to have it emulate an Xbox controller (seeing how there is no way to connect a PS3 controller to a PC and have it function properly out of the box). This causes the game to assume I have an Xbox controller, so when I want to see the control layout, and when the game gives me visual keypress prompts or tries to tell me which key is assigned to what, it uses Xbox button names and visuals.

This is naturally quite confusing.

Is there any way to have the game show me a PS3 controller's button names and visuals? I wouldn't even know if those visuals are buried somewhere inside the PC version or not.

Comment: 1. Print out an Xbox Controller photo. 2. Cut it out. 3. Glue it to your controller. 4. ??? 5. Success

Comment: @Marcelo Step 5 should be Profit :D

Comment: @Adanion That's very right, in my case, Step 5 is Total Failage then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because the PS3 game controller never was designed to be used with a computer, there have never been any computer games that has visualized the PS3 game controller button mapping layout.

Microsoft's close relationship to PCgaming (also through enabling it with extra accessory) has enabled the company to integrate the layout of the Xbox controller in most games. Sony's PlayStation division never wanted anything to do with PC gaming, Microsoft enabled it out of the box with their 360 Wired controller.

Your request is not possible without serious modding (in which case basically anything can be done).

Comment: I definitely follow your reasoning, but I was hoping that since the game was also playable on the PS3, that it would actually require relatively light modding.

Regardless, I'm pretty sure you are correct in saying this is not possible in any sensible manner.